# WatiN downloading a file from webpage

Tags: c#, watin

I have the following code which does a couple of webpage redirections and then clicks an  tag which has a JavaScript function as the href. When it is called a file is download.  My problem is I want to be able to download the file without being prompted to cancel, save or open. I am using IE9.

```
using (var browser = new IE("http:url.aspx")) {
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$UserName")).TypeText("cpereyra");
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$Password")).TypeText("Maxipereyra15");

    browser.Button(Find.ByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$LoginButton")).Click();


    browser.GoTo("http://it-motivity-cmc/Movation/MyPage/MyDashboard.aspx?dynamicdashboardid=ab000000-7dea-11c9-b596-d01e04bebb94");

    while (browser.Eval("document.readyState") != "complete") {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); 
    }

    Div div = browser.Div("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wrapper_vis_zone1_1");
    div.Link(link => link.Text == "Export to CSV").Click();
}
```

Comment: Here's what can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6184867/1113272

Comment: I've seen that but for some reason I can't reference FileDownloadHandler.

Comment: `WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.FileDownloadHandler` ? WatiN version?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check inside the js function, and then replicate the call it does to just download the file. To see the function, just open the js console ( F12 ) type the function name without parentheses, and the function body will appear. 
You will probably find a clean link inside the function.

Comment: That wouldn't work since he wants to download the file - it doesn't matter how you get the link, his problem is how to click on the Save button.