# WatiN error "hwnd cannot be IntPtr.Zero or null"

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, console, console-application, watin

I am getting this error when performing browser automation using WatiN.

[I am using this solution from a previous thread in order to acess the Save As dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19669074/3360348)

The code fails at the following line of the DownloadIeFile method.

```
AutomationElementCollection dialogElements = AutomationElement.FromHandle(windowDialog.Hwnd).FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
```

What's bizarre is that the code runs fine if there was already an instance of IE open on the machine. I have tried emulating this by:

1] create instance of a temporary browser
2] create browser object
    for manipulation
3] close both browser instances.s.

and this also fails.

FYI this is the code I am using:

```
class UpdateDiaryFigures
{ 


    public static void Start()
    {


        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        IE browser = new IE("http://www.example.com");
        //browser.Visible = false;
        Login(browser);

        string test = GetExport(browser, "AgentOpen", "01/10/2014", DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "Agent Name Ltd");

        //browser.Dispose();

    }


    static string GetExport(IE browser, string exportName, string fromDate, string toDate, string ddlValue)
    {

        browser.GoTo("http://www.example.com/ExcelExport.aspx");

        string open = "";

        switch (exportName)
        {
            case "AgentOpen":
            case "AgentClosed":
                if (exportName == "AgentClosed") { open = "Yes"; } else { open = "No"; }
                browser.TextField(Find.ById("txtAgentFromDate")).Value = fromDate;
                browser.TextField(Find.ById("txtAgentToDate")).Value = toDate;
                browser.SelectList(Find.ById("cboAgentCleared")).Select(open);
                browser.SelectList(Find.ById("cboAgent")).Select(ddlValue);
                browser.Image(Find.ById("btnPrintAgentRpt")).Click();
                break;
            case "AllAgentOpen":
                break;
            case "AllAgentClosed":
                break;
            case "CourtOpen":
            case "CourtClosed":
                break;
        }

        string filename = @"c:\Downloads\" + exportName
        browser.DownloadIeFile(filename);
        return filename;

    }

    static void Login(IE browser)
    {
        browser.TextField(Find.ByName("ctl00$cphMainContent$txtCompanyID")).Value = "ID";
        browser.TextField(Find.ByName("ctl00$cphMainContent$txtUserID")).Value = "user";
        browser.TextField(Find.ByName("ctl00$cphMainContent$txtPassword")).Value = "pass";
        browser.Button(Find.ByName("ctl00$cphMainContent$btnLogin")).Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like windowDialog.Hwnd is zero

Comment: Could it be a race condition that the new IE call hasn't started up Internet Explorer when you come to call DownloadFile so there us no window handle? That would explain why it works when there is an instance of IE running as you're just adding a tab to the existing IE process, thus a shorter startup time.

Comment: I've never worked with System.Windows.Automation before - how could this happen when the browser object is always being passed to the DownloadIeFile method?

Comment: Thanks for your response Allan - I'm not sure if that is the problem, because I have already opened and manipulated the IE object before the DownloadIeFile method is called...

Answer (score 1):

You may have multiple iexplore.exe process running even if you can only see one IE window. For example iexplore.exe and iexplore.exe*32