# Automatically download from links in browser using c# watin

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, automation, watin

Trying to automate file downloads, using Watin in IE. Have a 10 documents to be downloaded and i could find that the below code will prompt for download option.

```
string download_url="link to file";
browser.Goto(download_url);
```

I would like to automatically save these files into a new directory with custom names for each files. Is it possible without user prompt for saving files in IE(vesrion 8 and above). Please guide me with a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can find several other responses right here. Like this one:

[Downloading a file with Watin in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125285/downloading-a-file-with-watin-in-ie9)

```
using(IE ie = new IE(someUrlToGoTo))
{
    FileDownloadHandler fileDownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler(fullFileName);
    ie.AddDialogHandler(fileDownloadHandler);

    ie.Link("startDownloadLinkId").ClickNoWait();

    fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(15);
    fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(200);
}
```

Comment: thanks @ProgrammerV5  -but the download URL is of type: `http://example.com:8089/folder1/issueSearch.do?issues.export=Y` , which will download all contents of the table in the current view

Comment: Then you are selecting the wrong URL to download. You have to take a look at what is happening exactly on the download, at some point there is a URL that you can get your file correctly (after some script/event etc.)